# How to repair HTC Sensation XE with Beats Audio touch screen?

Tags: htc-sensation-xe, water-damage

I have bought a [HTC Sensation XE with Beats Audio](http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_sensation_xe-4164.php) and I am told apparently water got inside and cant be turn on. However when i disassemble it, saw nothing, any oxidation residue.

After some normal cleaning, I assembled the phone and tried to test it, it turns ON but unfortunately the screen does not work. Now I don't know what to do and changing the screen is expensive.

Is there any way to make this sort of problem out?

Comment: This is a rather complicated issue to deal with, while far from the device... Have you reopened the device and checked for any connection that didn't got well attached the first time around? _(first thing is always rechecking first steps taken)_ :)